# Uniformly magnetized sphere

Tags: magnetostatics

While working on a uniformly magnetized sphere, I have come across this problem: How does the boundary value equation $$\vec n.(\vec B_2-\vec B_1)=0$$ lead to the equation $$\phi_{out}|_{r=a}=\phi_{in}|_{r=a}$$ where, a is the radius of the sphere and $\phi$ is scalar potential?

Comment: What does the notation mean in the second equation?

Comment: The potential outside the sphere is equal to the potential inside the sphere.

Comment: You mean that the potential immediately outside the sphere equals the potential immediately inside the sphere?

Comment: Yes, and it is a magnetized sphere.

Comment: But the potential cannot change discontinuously?